# GitLab: Disconnect Files from a Repo

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I'll start off here saying this is the first time I've used git at any capacity, so I apologize if this is a stupid question. I've done research and couldn't find anything concrete.

I am trying to add in files to a repository in "Project A". The project i'm trying to add in, "Project B", is already part of it's own repository which is causing a "Dirty Submodule" error to happen and not allowing the commit. I was given "Project B" as a zipped file, and have no idea how it's still connected to it's own repo. I believe what Git wants me to do is commit the "Project B" changes that were made before I received the files, but I am unable to do that.

One idea I had to fix this issue is to "disconnect" Project B from it's repository so that they become simple, normal, non connected files on my local desktop. I believe this would allow me to put them into "Project A" without issue. Is this the best way to go about it, and if so, how do I go about accomplishing that? I am using TortoiseGit as well.

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your Project A repository to ignore the folder that contains Project B. You'll need to create a file in the root of Project A named `.gitignore`. This can contain any pattern of files and folders that you do not need git to manage.

- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore
- https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/ignoring-files

```
/projectA
    /folder1
    /folder2
    /projectB
    /folder3
    index.html
    .gitignore
```

In that file, just add

```
/projectB
```

and your projectA's git should ignore that folder entirely. Run `git status` at the root and it should not "see" that folder as needing to be added.

**EDIT (later that same day):**

One thing I didn't think of earlier is that this allows you to check out Project B into a subfolder of Project A and still use `git` to manage that project (pull updates, etc.) without impacting Project A.

Comment: This worked as well, another simple solution I found was just removing the .git files from ProjectB. Thank you so much for taking the time and giving me a less "hacky" solution!